# An exception occurred processing JSP page in jsp File

Tags: java, sql, jsp

my code is

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%!
Statement st,st1,st2,st3=null;
Connection conn,con,connn,con3=null;
%>
<%
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
st=conn.createStatement();
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
st1=con.createStatement();
connn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
st2=connn.createStatement();
con3=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
st3=con3.createStatement();
%>
```

while executing this file it showing error like

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /getcon.jsp at line 14

11: Connection conn,con,connn,con3=null;
12: %>
13: <%
14: Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
15: conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
16: st=conn.createStatement();
17: con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:xe","system","system");
```

I'm not able to get this error how to solve this error. i'm running this code through Tomcat **Webapps**. Please help me rectify this error.

Comment: It is really a BAD practice to create connection in JSP and executing Sql there. At least you can put this DB logic in your Servlet.

Comment: ok ... can you help me to run this code through this JSP file

Comment: Dang, why are you getting 4(!) different connections to the *same* database? Just get one and use it for all 4 statements. --- Do you really need 4 statements? Statement objects can be reused, though you can only have one resultset open at a time, per statement object. --- Also recommend *not* using user `system` when connecting to database.

Comment: Could you explain what are you going to do ? why this 4 `Connection` variables for ? Actually what you are intending to do ?

Comment: @Andreas can you please help me to resolve this error... I'm fully confused, here

Comment: @ShafinMahmud I have Registration.jsp file it included this code what I mentioned above code.. its a previous project .. now im modifying existing project .. but getting this error

Comment: Google [`how jsp jdbc`](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+jsp+jdbc) then read one of the many tutorials on how to write a JSP that connects to a database using JDBC.